# want to get start and end index of text(content)

Tags: javascript

I want to get the start and end index of the selected text(content) from the whole content using selectNodeContents() or document.createRange().

I have tried

```
<div id="parent">
 Hello everyone! <p id="demo_text">This is my home page</p>
</div>

var node = document.getElementById('demo_text');
var range = document.createRange();    
range.selectNodeContents(node);
```

I want,

```
startIndex = 16 // starting index of "This" from "Hello everyone! This is my home page"
endIndex = 35 // end index of "page" from "Hello everyone! This is my home page"
```

Comment: Why not use split on the string and then get the index of first and last?

Comment: Or are you trying to get the actual index position of the first letter of the first word, `This` and the first letter of the last word `page` in reference to the entire parent string?

Comment: It is unclear what you are looking for. Do you want to select the text? or do you actually just want the indexes as mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
function getSartEnd(elementID)
  {
  let el    = document.getElementById(elementID)
    , elTxt = el.textContent.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '').trim()
    , pTxt  = el.parentNode.textContent.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '').trim()
    , start = pTxt.indexOf(el.textContent)
    , end   = start + elTxt.length -1
    ;
  return { start, end }
  }

console.log( getSartEnd('demo_text') )
```

```html
  <div id="parent">
    Hello everyone! <p id="demo_text">This is my home page</p>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually just looking for the indexes, you can use [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) in combination with [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to locate your child element's `innerText` within the parent elements `innerText` which will return the start index. The end index can then be calculated by adding the length of the child string.

```js
const node = document.getElementById('demo_text');
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');

const startIndex = parent.innerText.indexOf(node.innerText);
const endIndex = startIndex+node.innerText.length-1;

console.log('startIndex: ', startIndex);
console.log('endIndex: ', endIndex);

console.log(parent.innerText[startIndex]);
console.log(parent.innerText[endIndex]);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
 Hello everyone! <p id="demo_text">This is my home page</p>
</div>
```

But if you are looking to select the string you will need to create a new `Selection` object using [`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) and add the range you have already created to it. [Example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNodeContents#live_sample)

```js
// Clear any current selection
const selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();

const node = document.getElementById('demo_text');
const range = document.createRange();   
range.selectNodeContents(node);

// Add the range to the empty selection
selection.addRange(range);
```

```css
::-moz-selection {
  background: pink;
}

::selection {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
 Hello everyone! <p id="demo_text">This is my home page</p>
</div>
```